# how to avoid changing localhost to domain.com when I push code from local to server

Tags: php, cakephp, web

I once used CakePhp, and when I push my code from local to server, 
I have to change something like a href="http://localhost/" on the local environment to http://domain.com/ everytime I push the code to server,

Later I know I can use  to avoid that.

But I have try that again, this time I do NOT use CakePhp, However I want to do something like  did, can somebody show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either :

- use config files and check their contents to create your links.
- check the domain name when creating your links.
- use relative links (`./` , `/` or `folder/`).
- define a host variable manually (not very clean, but probably the quickest way eg:

  ```
  <?php
      define(HOST, 'http://localhost'); //change that to http://domain.com when you upload your code)
  ?>
  ```

and build the links like that :

```
<img src="<?=HOST?>/img/random_image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: @Xinrui Ma ,  define a site url in bootstrap.php ,  you can use contents anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
href="/"
```

instead of

```
href="http://localhost/"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using HTML helper.

Doing $this->Html->link() will keep you away from the trouble.

Comment: Additionally, one should use a sane local setup (instead of localhost), as well: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/